# Find Total number of ways out of N Number taking K numbers every M interval

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have been stuck in a problem, that has thrown my brain out of the coding. This problem is at very high priority and I need the solution as early as possible. Problem is as :

There are exactly N advertising boards on the highway. Now a company want to advertise on some of these advertising boards(each advertising board costs some money) .

Company strategy is that, they want at least 'K' advertisement should be there among M consecutive advertising boards. But at the same time Company want to pay minimum for its advertisement .

Now, what is the total number of ways, different ways Company can advertise meeting its minimum cost strategy.

As for Example: N= 3, M = 2, K=1 ==> there is only one way for minimum cost, ie. 0C0 , where '0' denotes No company advertisement, and 'C' denotes company advertisement board.

Similarly, for N =4, M =2, K =1 ==> there is 3 possible ways, ie. C0C0, 0C0C, 0CC0.

Hope to get a reply from someone soon. Thanks.

Comment: so far I find a recursion for arbitrary N and M and K=1.

Comment: Thanks amiri. I have tried it using recursion, but for large N or a large difference between N & M, gives an unexpected output, that caused out of memory in my system.

Comment: I know, but I still think you could solve the problem with this approach unfortunately I'm at office right now and can't concentrate on this problem, but I think N module M would help you.

Comment: Thanks again Amiri. this time I am a bit confused about (N module M). I mean, i am not getting the exact algorithm that could find away the minimum cost. and thats the problem worst. Nevertheless, I still have time to solve it, You can help me reaching out at home.
And also, if you could explain me later the algorithm in detailed way, it will be highly appreciable.

Comment: I'll be at home in approximately 8 hours(it's just morning in here)   and then if I could I'll find a minimum algorithms for this. and from N module M I mean if you think that way it may reduce the time for your algorithm. didnt just use all the numbers below, use M previous numbers, I think that will help you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405305/combination-problem

Comment: It seems this was a competition problem --- http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431529/how-to-solve-this-combinatorics-problem-from-past-techgig-competition

Answer (score 1):

For $K=1$ there is a closed form.  The minimum number of billboards is $n=\lfloor \frac NM \rfloor$ and that number suffices if $N$ is increased to $(n+1)M-1$  Imagine a run of $M-1$ o's, a C, $M-1$ o's, a C, ... a C, and $M-1$ o's.  This is the only arrangement for $N=(n+1)M-1$.  Now if $N$ is lower, we can just erase the right number of o's.  These can be chosen n ${N-M \choose (M+1)\lfloor \frac NM \rfloor-N-1}$ ways.
I think the same approach works if $K$ divides $M$ but am not sure.

Comment: Thanks Ross. As I am not a professional mathematician, but I am pursuing internship in computer science. I have not much learned about floor function on a high level. I would be loving if you could explain the algo?

Btw, what I have found so far is that - 
case 1: if(M == K), result is always 1.

Case 2: if(N == M), result is always mCk . (M combination K)

case 3: if(N is divisible by M), result is 
1 + 2+ 3 + ....... + (M combination K)
Please guide me if I am wrong or right.

Also help me to find out what this value exact means ? 

{N-M \choose (M+1)\lfloor \frac NM \rfloor-N-1}

Comment: @PulkitSharma:  Let's take $K-1, M=6, N=19$.  You have to have three billboards, which you get with integer division (which is the floor) of $19/6$.  But with $3$ billboards, you could handle $N=23$ by the pattern 5o's,C,5o'sC,5o'sC,5o's.  Given that you only need $N=19$ you can delete any four of the o's.  My combination expression becomes ${20 \choose 4}$ as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Mr. Ross. I got this time what exactly means by that. Now when I am applying same algo for the sample, N =6, M =3, K =2 , it gives me output as (7C2) =21, while the correct output is 6.

Comment: @PulkitSharmaz:  That was supposed to be $K=1$ in the last comment.  I said I didn't know what to do for $K \gt 1$, but guessed that if $K$ divides evenly into $M$ we could use the same approach-space the C's with $\frac MK-1$ o's and then the number of choices will be to select which o's to delete.  For $M=3,K=2$ I have no idea, because the sides of the C's interact.