# Combination problem

Tags: combinatorics

There are N advertisement boards of which M consecutive boards should have at least K advertisements. How to find number of ways in which this is possible keeping cost minimum.
Eg: N=6,M=3,K=2 which has 6 possible ways: {1 1 0 1 1 0}, {0 1 1 0 1 1}, {0 1 1 1 1 0}, {1 0 1 1 1 0}, {0 1 1 1 0 1}, {1 0 1 1 0 1} [1=Ad,0=No Ad]
and when N=3,M=2,K=1 has only 1 possible way: {0,1,0} [since cost should be minimum(use least no of ads)]

N>=M>=K>=1

Comment: Do you mean that EVERY $M$ consecutive boards should have at least $K$ advertisements?

Comment: Yes... every M consecutive boards should have at least K advertisements

Answer (score 1):

First, let's deal with the case $N\leq M$. Clearly $K$ advertisements placed in any way will suffice as the minimum cost. There are ${N+K-1 \choose K}$ ways to arrange them in any way.

Now, let's deal with $N > M$.

**Hint:** Show that you need at least $\lfloor \frac{N}{M} \rfloor K$ advertisements.

**Hint:** Construct an explicit example to show that  $\lfloor \frac{N}{M} \rfloor K$ advertisements is sufficient.

This shows that $\lfloor \frac{N}{M} \rfloor K$ advertisements is the minimum cost.

Let $N_i$ denote the number of advertisements on the $i$th board.

**Hint:** Show that $N_i = N_{i+M}$, where the indices make sense.

**Hint:** If $N = mM + d$, then show that $N_1 = N_2 = \ldots N_d = 0 $.

This means that we must place $K$ advertisements in the remaining $M-d$ spots.

**Hint:** Show that any arrangement of $K$ advertisements into these $M-d$ spots will work.

**Hint:** Show that there are thus ${M-d+K -1 \choose K}$ ways to arrange them.

---

With $N=3, M=2, K=1$, we get $d=1$, and the answer of ${2-1+1-1 \choose 1} = 1$.

Comment: When N=3, M=3 and K=1 the result should be 1

Comment: How you are getting 1 \choose 1

Comment: I am asking for the case N=3,M=3 and K=1

Comment: @praveen Ah, my bad, I thought you were talking about the final example that you gave (which i used as an explicit value). I disagree that the number of arrangements should be 1. (Yes the number of advertisements is 1.) The result should be ${3 \choose 1} = 3$, as evidenced by $\{1,0,0\}, \{0,1,0\}, \{0,0,1\} $. If you read my proof, that should follow immediately.

Comment: for values of $(N,M,K)$ =(10,10,5) or (20,10,5) or .... (100,10,5) i am getting same result 2002

Comment: @praveen And ${14 \choose 5} = 2002$, so my result agrees with yours. I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: I am saying that it is not possible to have same result to all the values of N For (10,10,5) the result is 252. Not sure about the others

Comment: @Praveen? Why is it not possible? Read through what I wrote. The fact that $N_i = N_{i+M}$ greatly restricts the possibilities. I disagree that $(10,10,5)$ yields $252= {10 \choose 5}$, since you can place multiple advertisements on a board, instead of picking 5 unique boards to place the advertisement. Hence, the answer will be (much) greater than 252.