# How to solve this combinatorics problem from past TechGIG competition?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am not able to solve this problem from many days. It appeared on Final Round of May Challenge on TECHGIG.com. I am asking it here because, it requires strong maths concept of combinations.

**Problem Description:**

KFC opened just a new outlet. The problem is that its very outer of the main city. A long highway leads to that KFC outlet. Due to very outer position of outlet almost no one stops in it, hence its now unprofitable to hold it now. One of the main reason is that they have not advertised well for their outlet. There are exactly N advertising boards on the highway from main city to this new KFC outlet. Now KFC want to advertise on some of these advertising boards ( Definitely advertising on every board cost some money) .

KFC strategy is very clear, they want that at least 'K' KFC advertisement should be there among M consecutive advertising boards. But at the same time KFC want to pay minimum for its advertisement because already it has spent a lot on its outlet.

Now your job is to help KFC and tell KFC the number of ways different ways in which they can place their advertisement on there boards ( definitely minimum number of advertisement) and still meeting its strategy.

**Input/Output Specs:**
*Input Specification:*
Your input will be Three integers values. 
N advertising boards on the highway from main city to this new KFC outlet
at least 'K' KFC advertisement should be there among M consecutive advertising boards.
N, M and K (1 <= K <= M <= 50, M <= N <= 10^9)

*Output Specification:*
Your output will be total number of possible ways modulo 1000000007.
if the input values are invalid then your output will be "-1".

Comment: Was it sponsored by KFC? And above all, is it a real KFC outlet they are talking about, hence implying a ploy to solve their problem with as little expenditures as possible?

Comment: No, it wasn't sponsored by KFC. About the other question I can't surely say anything.

Comment: That is not a very hard combinatorics problem ; the only way to get such a minimal configuration is to equally distribute $k$ numbers mod $M$ (the equally means 'don't give more or less space to some pair of numbers unless you have to because there's not enough space'), and then duplicate the pattern over and over until you get it over all the $N$ boards.

Comment: Yeah, but we want to calculate how many such ways are there.

Comment: Ha. This problem (but without the KFC references) was posted here some time ago, probably while the contest was still live. It might be worth trying to find it - there might have been some answers posted. Wait - it's just over there, under "Related" --- http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399909/find-total-number-of-ways-out-of-n-number-taking-k-numbers-every-m-interval? And also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405305/combination-problem

Comment: I will try to find it..